# Instagram Invalid Response Error - 400

Tags: django, api, instagram, python-requests

I have the following code.

```
    params = {'client_id':settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_INSTAGRAM_KEY,
              'client_secret':settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_INSTAGRAM_SECRET,
              'aspect':'media',
              'object':'tag',
              'object_id':instance.hashtag,
              'callback_url':
                  'http://subdomain.domain.net:8000/campaigns/hook'}
    response = requests.post('https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions',
                             data=params)
```

And I get response

> '{"meta":{"error_type":"APISubscriptionError","code":400,"error_message":"Invalid
>   response"}}'

My domain is reachable from outside. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because Instagram sends a GET request to my callback_url
and wants me to response with `hub.challenge` parameter like below

```
    if self.request.GET:
            response = request.GET.get('hub.challenge')
            return HttpResponse(response)
```