# Identical POST requests for tag subscription yield different results

Tags: python, post, instagram

I'm using python script to subscribe for Instagram images with a specific tag. I'm sending a post request with urllib2, however, it returns an error 400:

```
"meta": {

    "code": 400,
    "error_message": "Invalid response",
    "error_type": "APISubscriptionError"
}
```

Reason: BAD REQUEST
Status: 400

## The code

```
import bottle
from bottle import route, post, run, request, response
from instagram import client, subscriptions

import urllib
import urllib2
import requests, time

bottle.debug(True)

api = client.InstagramAPI(client_id="CLIENTID", client_secret="CLIENTSECRET")

try:
    subscription_url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions'
    values = {'client_id' : 'CLIENTID', 
        'client_secret' : 'CLIENTSECRET',   
        'verify_token' : 'myVerifyToken',   
        'object' : 'tag',   
        'object_id' : 'fluxcapacitor',  
        'aspect' : 'media', 
        'callback_url' : 'http://mcfly.ngrok.com/callback' }

    data = urllib.urlencode(values)
    req = urllib2.Request(subscription_url, data)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except Exception, e:
    print e


@route('/callback')
@post('/callback')
def callback():
    mode = request.query.get("hub.mode")
    challenge = request.query.get("hub.challenge")
    verify_token = request.query.get("hub.verify_token")
    return challenge
run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8515, reloader=True)
```

For debugging I've added additional parameters in the request header to replicate POST request from [hurl.it](http://hurl.it) that actually works.

```
    headers = {'Content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept' : '*/*', 
        'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, compress',
        'User-Agent' : 'runscope/0.1'}
```

By posting the request in Hurl.it, Instagram API returns Status 200. I've used [Runscope](https://www.runscope.com/) compare feature for analyzing POST requests. The requests looks identical, the responses are different.

Comment: Is it exactly identical? Try comparing the captured request of hurl and your request.

Comment: Yeap. Exacly identical, down to User-Agent. Here is a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/moSnxpv.png
If anything was different, there would be green/red background colour.

Comment: Could it be this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607375/instagram-invalid-response-error-400